# getting jquery post data null inside python flask

Tags: jquery, python, flask

jquery ajax call

```
api_key=$('#acesskey').val();
    secret_key=$('#sacesskey').val();
    provider_name = $('#cname').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {api_key:api_key,secret_key:secret_key,provider_name:provider_name},
        url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/login",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {
            alert(data.status);
            if(data.status == "True")
            {
                custom_ready();         
            }
        }
    });
```

python flask code

```
provider_name=request.args.get('provider_name')
api_key=request.args.get('api_key')
secret_key=request.args.get('secret_key')
print provider_name
print api_key
print secret_key
```

output
None
None
None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax call code

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/login',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {akey:akey,sakey:sakey,pname:pname},
    success: function(response){
        alert(response.status);
    }
});
```

HTML FORM

```
<form action="" method="POST">
</form>
```

Python code

```
akey = request.form['akey']
sakey = request.form['sakey']
pname = request.form['pname']
```

Answer (score 4):

`request.args` contains the query string parameters (like `bar` in `/foo?bar=42`). You are doing a POST request and want to look in `request.form`.

See here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#the-request-object

Comment: oky, so what i need to change in ajax call ? i changed python file according to instruction but still its not working.. status code 400  so i think i need to change ajax call also .. can you give me simple example ?

Comment: Post your whole view function that is supposed to handle this request. Run the dev server with `debug=True`. Post full tracebacks if there are any.